# Generating a SHA-256 Hash with trailing zeroes

Tags: sha256

Using Linux terminal I'm able to generate hashes with leading zeroes, but I'm confused on how I would be able to generate hashes based on the number of trailing zeroes.

Comment: The hash depends on the input you want to hash. To get a different hash you simply change the input. What exactly is your question or the actual problem?

Comment: @Progman I'm trying to generate a list of hashes based on certain parameters. I'm able to get hashes with a number of leading zeros based on input, but now I'm  stuck on producing hashes that consist of trailing zeros.

Comment: Finding a hash with trailing zeros is the same as finding a hash with leading zeros. You simply change the input until you find a hash which fits your conditions. What is the problem in finding the hashes with trailing zeros when you already know how to find hashes with leading zeros?